# How does CPython keep track of the type of an object

Tags: python, class, oop

I am learning about classes and wanted to find out how python keeps track of what the type of an object is. I would imagine, that it is easy to tell what the type of an int is because it is a built in type

```
but now suppose, I have the following code: 
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self._x=x
        self._y=y

    def draw(self):
        print(self._x, self._y)
p1=Point(1,2)
```

How does python know that this object is of type p. I understand, that if I wanted to know the type of p1, I would call `type(p1)`, but I was wondering how the type is represented in memory. I thought that it is an attribute inherited from the `object` class that gets set when I call the constructor, but when I call `print(object.__dict__)`, there is no type attribute.

Comment: `print(p1.__class__)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to confuse you with metaclasses yet, so I'll be giving a brief explanation. The `__class__` attribute of an object returns the class of that instance, which you are referring "type" here.

```
p1.__class__
```

returns this.

```
__main__.Point
```

The `__main__` is the module and `Point` is the class obviously.

However there is more than this. Classes are also objects and when you call

```
Point.__class__
```

It returns `type`, and `type` is a metaclass in Python. Basically the class of a class is type.

Comment: You should also read python data model in order to understand how Python language works.

Answer (score 1):

Builit-in [dir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) will give you list of valid attributes for that object.

Your example:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self._x=x
        self._y=y

    def draw(self):
        print(self._x, self._y)
p1=Point(1,2)
```

Then

```
print(dir(p1))
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_x', '_y', 'draw']
```